# Создание БД для task-менеджера

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, у меня такой вопрос. Есть сайт с возможностью регистрации. Зарегистрированный пользователь может добавлять Task-таблицы, а в них свои задания. В чём вопрос, как реализовать структуру БД, ведь пользователи сами дают имена своим таблицам? Извините за довольно примитивный вопрос

Comment: Никаких изменений структуры при пользовательском вводе не должно быть - только изменения данных в таблицах. По запросу в гугле "One to Many отношения между таблицами" вам подскажет как сделать правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пользователь не может создавать таблицы в БД, но можно описать таблицу, содержащую имя таблицы, связанную с пользователем и таблицу, в которой будет описаны поля создаваемой таблицы. Немного некрасиво расписал, так что прилагаю схему (примерную)[image: схема бд]

Comment: Благодарю за ответ)